# How to call a function dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I have in vb a selector

```
Dim ver =101
Select Case ver
        Case 101
            upd101()
        Case 102
            upd102()
        Case 103
            upd103()
    End Select
```

How can I make this select better by calling function in more dynamically in this form:
 with the prefix "upd" followed by a ver integer..?

thank you!
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its possible but its not cleaner, or faster.

```
Dim t As Type = base.GetType()

t.GetMethod("upd" + theInt)
```

Comment: what is obj ?   Dim obj As New Object

Comment: That help?  Is the type of the class that all of your methods are defined in.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just call upd(param)?

I mean, rather than creating many functions, create one and use variables. ;]

Comment: Come now that would be foolish.

Comment: I don;t understand what you mean, could you tell a little bit more?

Comment: Sorry, if English is not your first language you might not read the sarcasm.

Comment: Yes, I am from Poland, but now I understand. ;] In polish, we would say something like "no co ty?" - in English: "dude! really?". ;]

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim ver as Integer 
dim procToCall as String

ver = 101
procToCall = "upd" & ver

CallByName myclassInstace, procToCall, vbMethod
```

EDIT: Here `myClassInstance` is the instance of the class you have created.
i.e. lets assume you have a class named `Person` which has a method named `ToString`.
The code will look like

```
dim somePerson as new Person
CallByName somePerson, "ToString", vbMethod
```

However, avoid using this style of programming.
How many such methods exist for you to call the method in this form?

Comment: tnx, so I have the functions  upd101() to ... upd150()

Comment: and I what to replace the selector to some lighter ... like  upd{101}() ..? is this posible ???

Comment: it give me an error: Public member 'upd100' on type 'frm' not found.

Comment: CallByName(Me, procToCall, vbMethod)

Comment: How would you do this with protected methods?

Comment: @JeffPuckett: You will have to rely on reflection to call protected methods.